# Use pty with ssh2 in node to execute command with sudo

Tags: node.js, ssh, libssh2

I need to launch a command with sudo over ssh using npm ssh2 module for node.js;
only reading module's documentation I can't figure out how to use the pty option:

```
ssh.on('ready', function() {

    //not working sudo command:
    ssh.exec('cd /var/www/website && sudo mkdir myDir', { pty: true }, function(err, stream) {
        if (err) throw err;

        stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {

            console.log('exit code: ' + code + ' signal: ' + signal);

            ssh.end();
        });
    });

}).connect({
    host: configuration.sshAddress,
    port: 22,
    username: configuration.sshUser,
    password: configuration.sshPass
});
```

Can someone explain the correct use of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to parse the `stream` output for the sudo prompt. At that point, you have to `stream.write(password + '\n');`. The alternative to doing all of that is to modify `/etc/sudoers` so that the logged in user can execute sudo for a specific program/script/whatever without a password.

Comment: I can't get this to work. How/where do I add the `stream.write(password + '\n');`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should place the `stream.write(password + '\n');` right after the `stream.on('exit',....` line.