# Reboot Linux with SSH command

Tags: node.js, ssh

I'm using simple-ssh with nodeJS and expressJS, and I'm trying to reboot a remote linux machine with ssh command, this is my code (it does not work, but if I try to execute a ls command that works.) help please!

```
ssh.exec('shutdown -r now', {
out: function(stdout) {
     console.log(stdout)}}).start();
```

Comment: Did you try logging stderr as well? Perhaps that may hint at what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm sure the user executing the command has sufficient privileges to run `ls`, do they have enough `reboot`? Check the logs!

**EDIT**: post revised to include my answer below. I provided it in a comment to this answer after the OP confirmed they have sufficient perms:

Given your reply that your user has `sudo` privileges, note that `sudo`'s default behaviour is to prompt for a password.

To use the `visudo` editor (e.g. `sudo visudo`) to allow a given *username* to run the `reboot` command without a password prompt, try adding the following lines to your configuration:

```
username ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/reboot 
Defaults!/path/to/reboot !requiretty
```

Your *username* should no longer be prompted, and your call to `ssh.exec()` should work as desired. You can follow a similar pattern for any other command you need to run as another user / root.

If you need to determine the */path/to/reboot* for your particular system use the command: `sudo which reboot`

Comment: Yes I have privileges

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

If your user has sudo privileges, the default behaviour is to prompt for a password.

Use `visudo` (e.g. `sudo visudo`) and to allow a given username to run the `reboot` command try the settings:
`username ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/reboot` followed by another line `Defaults!/path/to/reboot !requiretty`

If you need to determine `/path/to/reboot` use the command: `sudo which reboot`

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tried ssh.exec but unless you’re logged in as root, you can only call shutdown with sudo.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840459/how-do-i-execute-sudo-command-over-ssh-in-node-js

Comment: This should also help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559265/use-pty-with-ssh2-in-node-to-execute-command-with-sudo

Answer (score 0):

systemctl reboot -i

is the command for all linux machine rebooting condition.

Answer (score -1):

To reboot your Linux pc using command line use:

```
sudo reboot
```

Enter your `sudo` password
Wait system will reboot automatically

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).