# Node ssh2 to ssh and sudo su as a user and run commands

Tags: node.js, sudo, su, ssh2

Using node ssh2 module, this is what I need to do
1. ssh to a server as a local user
2. sudo as oracle : sudo su oracle
3. run commands

I am unable to sudo su oracle and hence cant run any commands.
The local user has the privilege to become oracle and so no password need to be provided.

I can run multiple commands as one like -
cd /home;./run.sh

But If i need to run commands where the first command is 
sudo su oracle;cd /home; ./run.sh

I don't get a response

//code snippet

```
let fs = require('fs'),
  Client = require('ssh2').Client;
const executeRemote = (command, remoteServer, user, privateKey) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let conn = new Client();
    let outputData = '';
    console.log('privatekey is ' + privateKey);
    conn.on('ready', function () {
      conn.exec((command), function (err, stream) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        stream.on('close', function (code, signal) {
          console.log('outputData is ', outputData);
          console.log('code is ' + code);
          if (code === 0)
            resolve(outputData);
          else
            reject(outputData);

          conn.end();
        }).on('data', function (data) {
          //console.log('data is ', data.toString());
          outputData = outputData + data.toString();
        }).stderr.on('data', function (data) {
          console.log('stderr data Error- ' + data.toString());
          //check if data.toString() has WARNING
          let regex = '[WARNING]';
          if (data.toString().match(regex))
            outputData = outputData + data.toString();
          else
            reject(new Error('Failed to run the command- ' + command + ' .Error- ' + data.toString()));
        });
      });
    }).connect({
      host: remoteServer,
      port: 22,
      username: user,
      privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync(privateKey)

    });
  });
};
```

Once I can ssh as local user, I want to run the command to sudo as oracle and then run other commands.
Is there a code snippet some one can share how they sudo su as any user and then run commands

Comment: How can I disable Disable pseudo-tty allocation ?  Tried  conn.exec((command), {pty:false}, function (err, stream) {....} Didnt help.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559265/use-pty-with-ssh2-in-node-to-execute-command-with-sudo) question's answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the password on prompt:

```
ssh.exec('sudo su - ' + sudoUserName, { pty: true }, function (err, stream) {
stream.on('close', (code, signal) => {
        //clean up
}).on('data', (data) => {

    if (data.toString().substring(0, sudoUserName.length) === sudoUserName) {
        //logged in successfully
    }
    else {
        //enter password
        stream.write(password + '\n');
    }

}).stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    stream.close();
});
}
```